Pourquoi au 19ème siècle s'invectivait-on avec "Vous êtes un peintre, Monsieur !". Qu'est-ce que cela voulait signifier ?
Dans les écrits ou tribunes du 19ème siècle, quand s'interpellent rudement des personnes qui se fâchent, il n'est pas rare qu'un "Vous êtes un peintre, Monsieur !" fuse.
Mais qu'est-ce l'on reprochait alors à la cible de cette insulte ?

Qu'un peintre avait une vie dissolue ?
Que l'on était malhabile, irréfléchi ?
Ou que l'on était un menteur, dépeignant quelque-chose de forgé et faux, comme si un peintre l'avait imaginé ?


Pourrait-on avoir quelques exemples d'utilisation de cette expression au XIXe siècle ? Elle ne semble pas courante.

Un pleutre ? un pitre ?

En argot militare (XIXème) , c'est un balayeur. On rencontre peut-être ce terme dans des pièces de comique troupier en vogue sur les boulevards vers 1900.

C'est long, le 19è siècle... pas moyen de dater ça plus précisément: 1er Emp.+Restauration, Louis-Ph., 2nd Empire, 3ème Rép. ? En ts cas le dictionnaire de Vidocq ne dit rien. Le mieux c'est ce que propose @Graffito: peintre = balayeur/de corvée de balayage, pinceau=balai.

« il n'est pas rare »... « fuse » : il faudrait quelques citations en soutien de cette affirmation parce que la seule occurrence que je connaisse est dans la correspondance de Victor Hugo. Et dans le contexte où Hugo  l'utilise ce n'est pas une insulte mais un compliment.

Je suis entrain de les chercher sur Gallica, qui indexe aussi des journaux.
